# await is not awaiting for the the key inside the awaited valiable

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

This is unexpected for me, but this seems to be some issue with async-await itself. I am using node v8.0

For the code below:

```
(async function(){
  var userProfile = await (myApiHelper.getUserProfile(userName));
  console.log(userProfile);
  console.log(userProfile.location);
}());
```

In above code,

```
console.log(userProfile)
```

, prints the correct data:

> {"name": "abc", "location": "Bangalore"};

But

```
console.log(userProfile.location)
```

> prints undefined.

Can anyone please help me here, if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: `userProfile` is string ?

Comment: Can we see how `getUserProfile` works? Does it return JSON?

Comment: Thank you @MukeshSharma and AndrewLi , by default request.get was returning string value. When I passed json: true, it started returning Object.
My issue solved.